# What are the alternatives for Draggable and Droppable plugins in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I had been using draggable and droppable plugins for a long time and now i am facing a performance issue as i had to write a lot of javascript and DB call operations for a functionality that i should be implementing for 2.0 version of the application.

I have tested the code in some of the latest browsers, but did not give me good luck. I have started exploring different jQuery plugins to use for the 2.0 version of the application.

Before deciding on using a plugin I am looking for suggestions based on your experience with different plugins. I will compare and cross check with the features before using them and also i will post my findings as well.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: Requests for resources like this re off topic but it's not hard to find numerous different libraries for drag/drop

Comment: Currently i am testing draggability.js with some sample code. But i just wanted to see if there are any .js as efficient as draggable and droppable.